# Why are the MessureSpec constants in Android -2147483648, 1073741824, 0

Tags: java, android

The **MessureSpec** constant is:

```
public static final int AT_MOST = -2147483648

public static final int EXACTLY = 1073741824

public static final int UNSPECIFIED = 0
```

I know the top 2 bits are 10, 01, 00.

But I do not know why it is.

Comment: Pretty sure the comment in the doc is your answer: MeasureSpecs are implemented as ints to reduce object allocation. This class is provided to pack and unpack the <size, mode> tuple into the int.  My interpretation is they wanted to use one int to represent both the size and the mode and so chose to use the upper 2 bits for mode.

Comment: Thanks Andy.
I solved this question : )

Answer (score 0):

It's a coding pattern (habit?) from assembler and C that's also common in embedded and graphics programming because it translates into compact machine level instructions. If you look at the hexadecimal values:

```
AT_MOST      0x80000000
EXACTLY      0x40000000
UNSPECIFIED  0x00000000
```

Since AT_MOST and EXACTLY are single bits you can test for them separately or together with bit masks e.g.:

```
if ((measurespec & AT_MOST) != 0) { .. } 

if ((measurespec & (AT_MOST | EXACTLY) != 0) { .. }

if (measurespec == UNSPECIFIED) { .. }
```

In assembler it translates to compact, fast jumps - roughly:

```
AND measurespec 0x80000000
JNZ 

AND measurespec 0xC0000000
JNZ 

AND measurespec measurespec
JZ
```

Some instruction sets include jumps/tests for single bits which is even more compact.

The JVM instruction set equivalents are:

```
if_icmpeq  (branch if two ints are equal)

if_icmpne  (branch if two ints are equal)
```